# shell script and and and

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have this script but is not working, i've tried with && instead -a but does not work. the idea is exit with error when the parameter $1 is different to 'normal' , 'beta' and 'stable

```
if [ [ "$1" != "normal" ]  -a [ "$1" != "beta" ] -a [ "$1" != "stable" ] ]; then
    echo "Error, type parameter mode version: normal, beta, stable"
    exit
else
    echo "Site: ${1}"
fi
```

I've tried too with:

```
if [ [ "$1" != "normal" ]  && [ "$1" != "beta" ] && [ "$1" != "stable" ] ]; then
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple ANDs, use

```
if [ condition ] && [ condition ] && [ condition ]
then
   code
fi
```

This works with OR (`||`) too, for example

```
if [ "$1" = "normal" ] || [ "$1" = "beta" ] || [ "$1" = "stable" ]
then
    printf 'Site: %s\n' "$1"
else
    echo 'Error, type parameter mode version: normal, beta, stable' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

In your case, you could also use:

```
case "$1" in
    normal|beta|stable)
        printf 'Site: %s\n' "$1" ;;
    *)
        echo 'error' >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

Comment: thanks, it's workign with if [  "$1" != "standard" ]  && [ "$1" != "beta" ] && [ "$1" != "stable" ]
then    //  then is  in the second line

Comment: @stackdave The newline before `then` may be replaced by `;` as you had in the question. I put it on a new line because of the many conditions.